# finding the equation of the tangent on the point on the curve where the derivative at that point is undefined.

Tags: limits

Consider $f(x)=x^\frac15\tan x+7x+5$.
the derivative of this function is $\frac{1}{5}\frac{\tan x}{x^\frac45}+x^\frac15\sec^2x+7$
the derivative of the function is undefined at $x=0$
but I have been taught that the method to calculate the slope of the tangent at x=x1 if the derivative is not defined at $x=x_1$ is to calculate the
$\lim_\limits{x\to x_1}f '(x)$.
If the value of the limit is finite, then that would be the slope of the tangent at that point.
So the slope of the tangent to the point $x=0$ at the curve $f(x)=x^\frac15\tan x+7x+5$ is
$\lim_\limits{x\to 0} f '(x)=7$
hence slope of tangent is $7$
I am unable to understand the reasoning behind
1)why the derivative does not exist(graph looks smooth at $x=0$)
2)if the derivative does not at the point exist, then how can the slope of the tangent exist at that point?
(According to my current understanding, the only situation where the tangent exist but derivative does not exist  is when the tangent is vertical  where slope and derivative does not exist but tangent exist)
the graph of the function
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> finding the equation of the tangent on the point on the curve where the derivative at that point is undefined.

If $f$ is not differentiable at $a$, then $f$ has no tangent line at $a$ or has a vertical tangent. **But** $f(x)=x^{1/5}\tan(x)+7x+5$ **is differentiable** at $0$.

The problem here is that $x^{1/5}$ is not differentiable at $0$, so you cannot use the Product Rule to compute $f'(0)$. Since you cannot use the Product Rule, the simplest is to come back to the definition of derivative: we have

$$
\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0} = \frac{x^{1/5}\tan(x)+7x}{x} = \frac{x^{1/5}}{\cos(x)}\frac{\sin(x)}{x} + 7
$$

But $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1$, $\lim_{x\to 0}\cos(x)=1\neq 0$, $\lim_{x\to 0}x^{1/5}=0$ so Limit Laws imply that

$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0} = 7
$$

Therefore, $f$ is differentiable at $0$ and $f'(0)=7$.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Taylor series of $\tan(x)$ around $x=0$, you have
$$f(x)=5+7 x+x^{6/5}+\frac{x^{16/5}}{3}+O\left(x^{21/5}\right)$$ then no problem